# switch without diode

Tags: switches, testing

I have a project where I need to put a switch in between the resource from tester and the DUT.
My DUT is a 48 pin device (semiconductor IC), each of the pins has its own ESD diode. The switch, for example, can be an ADG1612.

FYI on my project : 
I need to do a continuity test. It is to check if the DUT exists or is placed properly in the socket by measuring the DUT's ESD protection diode. The test method is to apply current and measure the voltage, expecting ~ 0.6v.

My tester resource has already shorted the Force and Sense pins, so there is no way to use Force and Sense to detect if DUT is place correctly in socket.

Since there is a switch in between resource and DUT, it will still get a diode measurement if the DUT does not exist because it is checking the ESD diode of the switch now.

For the DUT pin which connects directly to resource, it will get clamp value if there is no DUT connected or get a real diode measurement if the DUT does exist.

my question is:
Is there any switch on the market (from AD, TI..etc) that has a switch without an ESD diode? Or called a flying diode? 
Or is there any switch on the market that will not affect/confuse the diode measurement?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the magnitude of the voltage being switched?  What are the switch requirements: on resistance, bandwidth, control voltage, etc?

Comment: Make your own switch with mosfets if an integrated one won't work

Comment: When you say "resource" do you mean "source"?

Comment: Can you power the analog switch independently of the DUT?  If you power the switch with a rail that's at least 0.6V below ground and a rail at least 0.6V above ground (I'd go with 1V to be sure), then the switch's diodes wouldn't be involved.  If my question makes no sense, could you post a schematic fragment that illustrates how your DUT, switch, and tester are connected together?

Comment: In my experience the "switch" you are looking for is an electromechanical relay. I have fond memories of listening to the relays click as the continuity test is performed.

Comment: If you are dead-set on using a solid state solution, I would suggest a switch with an integrated charge pump such as the [MAX14777](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/MAX14777.html). It can be powered from a 3.3 to 5V supply, but can switch voltages that extend far beyond the power rails. Otherwise, I agree with @ElliotAlderson: use a relay.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thanks for the reply. finally, i choose a relay from Omron G6K-2G-Y. it stated it has the smallest mounting area. anyone of you know if there is any other type of relay that even has smaller mounting area? my PCB is around 4cm X 3 cm, so this size is consume quite alot of my PCB area.